# Equivalent to Bash alias in PowerShell

Tags: django, powershell

A newbie PowerShell question:

I'd like to make an alias in PowerShell exactly equivalent to this Bash alias:

```
alias django-admin-jy="jython /path/to/jython-dev/dist/bin/django-admin.py"
```

In tinkering with it so far, I've found this to be very difficult.

-PowerShell aliases only work with PowerShell commands + function calls

-No clear way to allow for an unlimited number of arguments on a PowerShell function call

-PowerShell seems to block stdout

---

It's worth noting that I've tried the solution put forth here: http://huddledmasses.org/powershell-power-user-tips-bash-style-alias-command/

And have gotten the following syntax-related error on loading up PowerShell:

---

```
The term 'which' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spell
ing of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Dan\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:9 char:27

+             $cmd = @(which <<<<  $_.Content)[0]
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (which:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**PowerShell aliases do not allow for *arguments***.
They **can only refer to a command *name***, which can be the name of a cmdlet or a function, or the name / path of a script or executable.

To get what you are after, **you need to define a *function***:

```
function django-admin-jy {
    jython.exe /path/to/jython-dev/dist/bin/django-admin.py @args
}
```

This uses a feature available since PowerShell 2.0 called argument [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting): you can apply `@` to a variable name that references either an array or a hashtable.
In this case, we apply it to the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) named `args`, which contains all arguments (that weren't bound to *explicitly declared parameters* - see [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions)).

If you want a truly generic way to create aliases functions that take parameters, try this:

```
function New-BashStyleAlias([string]$name, [string]$command)
{
    $sb = [scriptblock]::Create($command)
    New-Item "Function:\global:$name" -Value $sb | Out-Null
}

New-BashStyleAlias django-admin-jy 'jython.exe /path/to/jython-dev/dist/bin/django-admin.py @args'
```

Comment: One benefit with using functions is that you get auto-complete for argument names (press tab after `-`) that you don't get for aliases set with the generic `New-BashStyleAlias`. Defining functions is a little bit more verbose but it shouldn't be a problem in profile scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can have arbitrarily many arguments. You just need to use `$args` to access them.

As for the stdout issue: What exactly are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for a while and I've written this PowerShell module:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/HackF5.ProfileAlias

https://github.com/hackf5/powershell-profile-alias

To get started you install it by:

```
Install-Module HackF5.ProfileAlias
Register-ProfileAliasInProfile
```

Then use it like:

```
Set-ProfileAlias dkfeed 'Enter-Docker feed_app_container' -Bash
```

I've been using it for a while myself and I've found it fairly useful.

(It only runs on PS 7.0 as I wrote it for myself).

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer 13 years later from chatgpt:

To set an alias in PowerShell, use the New-Alias cmdlet. For example:

```
New-Alias -Name myAlias -Value "my commands"
```

To make the alias permanent, add this command to your PowerShell profile script. Find the profile script path with $PROFILE. Edit or create the script with a text editor.