# Set alias for Nodejs with harmony argument in Powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell, command-line, command-prompt, koa

Im need to using `node --harmony` each time when working with node.recently im working with [koajs](http://koajs.com) and in the home page of koajs sayed can use this command

```
alias node='node --harmony'
```

but when i calling this command on powershell i get this error :

```
alias : This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name     'node=node --harmony' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ alias node='node --harmony'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node=node --harmony:String) [Get-Alias],   ItemNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAliasCommand
```

so how can change alias of node to node with harmony argument?

Comment: That command is for Bash-style shells such as you'd find on OS X or Linux. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2486303/445398) and some of the other answers to that question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent to Bash Alias in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468145/equivalent-to-bash-alias-in-powershell)